# React backgroundImage doesn't consistently work

Tags: reactjs, react-multi-carousel

When my component is used inside another component, the backgroundImage inline style works as expected. However when used inside an [react-multi-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-carousel) the inline styles are no longer working.

Dev tools shows that the styles are in effect, just not visible on the screen for some reason.
The backgroundImage is a url, however hardcoded images also do not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import { Product } from "../../types";

interface IMasonryPostProps {
    product: Product;
    showOverlay?: boolean;
}

export default function MasonryPost({
    product,
    showOverlay = true,
}: IMasonryPostProps) {
    const backgroundImage = {
        backgroundImage: `url('${product.image}')`,
        color: "red",
    };
    const style = { ...backgroundImage, ...product.style };
    const overlay = showOverlay ? "overlay" : "";
    console.log(style);
    return (
        <a
            className={`masonry-post ${overlay}`}
            href={product.image}
            style={style}
        >
            <div className="product-text">
                <div className="category-container">{product.category}</div>
                <div>
                    <h2 className="product-name">{product.title}</h2>
                    <span className="product-price">{product.price}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    );
}
```

Comment: and is it working if you don't use an image as a background but put it as a `src` property inside <img> tag?

Comment: btw, you're using `className={`masonry-post ${overlay}`}` can it be that it overrides the backgroundImage property?

Comment: img with src does work. Im just curious why background image doesn't.

Comment: @J Doe, you override it with `product.style` maybe there's `backgroundImage` in it somewhere

Comment: As it turns out, I just needed to explicitly set `display: block;` to the masonry post element with the background image. Any idea why that is the case?